# Is there a standard representation for "vanilla" numbers that is culture independent?

Tags: standards, iso

I'm writing a specification and need to specify the a culture neutral string representation of numeric values. Something like ISO-8601 for dates.

Preferably I'd like my numeric values to be expressed as "decimal numbers in standard notation with '.' as the decimal separator character and no thousands separator, trailing zeros optional."
E.g. eight thousand and a half would be represented by "80000.5" or "80000.50"

Is there a standard for this specification, or a standard for any culture neutral representation that can be unambiguously parsed?

I've looked at currency specifications, but the only seem to deal with the symbols/currency codes. 
ISO-30 looks promising but takes not definitive stance on the decimal separator.

Comment: `en-US`, without commas? I don't know of any "standard", though .. I wonder what Microsoft/.NET uses for Culture Invariant. Perhaps from SI?

Comment: Yeah, there is no lack of renderers and parsers for the format (C scanf with %d). I can't understand why there is no standard or why it is so difficult to find.

Comment: Probably, the need has not been there. People are pretty good at unambiguously recognizing numeric values, even if they are 'incorrectly' formatted for their culture. For dates there was a need, because there was ambiguity about which date is represented by "01/02/03" depending on cultural formatting.